# json get index of iteration on http://www.json-generator.com/

Tags: javascript, json

I need a json file that will contain some dummy data so I started using http://www.json-generator.com

Now I'm trying to get the object index of each completed -> item.

Go to http://www.json-generator.com and paste in the code below and click "Generate".
As you can see, item index becomes 0 each time.. I would like to have it incremental.

```
[
'{{repeat(4)}}', {
    userId: '{{index}}',
    user: '{{guid}}',
    email: '{{email}}',
    completedItems: [
        '{{repeat(2,9)}}', {
            item: [{
                id: '{{index}}',
                createdTime: '{{date(YYYY-MM-dd:hh:mm)}}',
                live: '{{bool}}',
                title: '{{lorem(3)}}',
                markedAsFun: [
                    '{{repeat(1,3)}}', {
                        markedBy: '{{firstName}} {{surname}}',
                        mark: function(idx1) {
                            var choices = [
                                "Yes",
                                "no"
                            ];
                            return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
                        }

                    }


                ],
                charsCount: [
                    '{{numeric(130, 500, integer)}}'
                ]
            }]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: You should give more details, at least add more tags.

Answer (score 0):

[image: View this]

The json it is creating in my case has the id value incremented.

Answer (score 0):

"To get the index of iteration of the array of objects generated create a function/method with parameter indexObject or any name you prefer, but remember it will be an object and inside that function/method call that object by property currentIndex, example indexObject.currentIndex."

```
[
  '{{repeat(10, 10)}}',
  {
    index: '{{index()}}',
    charByIndex: function(indexObject){
      var myArray = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"];
      var currentIndex = indexObject.currentIndex;
      return myArray[currentIndex];
    }
  }
]
```

[Screenshot with example from json-generator.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31WPv.png)